# How to get year wise spending on salaries using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `employees` table with their name, hire_date and salary on it. Now what I am trying to get is the each year's spending of the company on salaries, but every time I try to do it, it gives me each hire_date in the output and respective salary.

```
select 
    hire_date, dateadd(year, 1, hire_date), sum(salary) 
from 
    employees
where 
    hire_date between hire_date and dateadd(year, 1, hire_date)
group by 
    hire_date
```

Comment: You "group by" it's not correct and should fail. When you group by you must pass all the expressions forming the select but the grouping column: group by hire_date,DATEADD(Year, 1, hire_date)

Comment: What if an employee leaves the company? Shouldn't you have a `leave_date` column as well in your table to hold that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your requirements. If you need the total salary cost per year it is implied you use `SUM` on salary and `GROUP BY` year:

```
select 
    YEAR(hire_date), SUM(salary) 
from 
    employees
group by 
    YEAR(hire_date)
```